# Aggregation Calculation for All Items with Data rolling from Some Previous Data Points

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, aggregate-functions, partitioning

How do I do aggregation calculations on data rolling from previous data points?

For example, I have a table for the property value evaluations.  Each data point is only for a property.

```
"Property Value Evaluation"

Date        Property   Value
1/5/2017    A          10
2/3/2017    B          8
2/20/2017   B          12
3/1/2017    A          9
4/10/2017   B          15
```

And assuming that the property value stays the same as it was evaluated last time, until it is evaluated again.  For example, the value of Property A was 10 on 1/5, and it stayed 10 until 3/1 when it was re-evaluated as 9.

How can I have a report to show the trend of the values of all the properties?  That is, I need to include all the properties on every data point of the report, such as:

```
"Value Trend of All Properties"

Date        Total   Average
1/5/2017    10      10
2/3/2017    18      9
2/20/2017   22      11
3/1/2017    21      10.5
4/10/2017   24      12
```

(Where Total is the sum of the values of Property A and Property B, and Average is the average value of these two.)

The problem I have is, for the sub-query which takes the Date and the Property as the parameters and returns the last Value, the following error occurs, even though my subquery is "select LAST_VALUE([Value]) ..." which only returns 1 value:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: What database are you using, and have you tried something yet?

Comment: SQL Server database.  Have also thought about using CTE, but have not figured out how to do.

Comment: Your results and your description don't make sense.  Where does the 24 come from?  It should be 15 because there is only one data point on that day.

Comment: Please note my statement after the first table, "Assuming that the property value stays the same as it was evaluated last time, until it is evaluated again.". That is, for example, for 4/10/2017, when we are calculating the "Total Value", we need to include the values of both Properties, even thought there is only one data point (for Property B) on that day in the first table.  Thus we need to add the value of Property A (which was 9, evaluated on 3/1) and the value of Property B (which was 15, evaluated on 4/10), so the total is (9+15=) 24.

Comment: on 2/20/2017 , total is 20 (8+12) or 22 .?

Comment: on 2/20/2017, the total of the values of both Properties is: 10 (Property A, previously evaluated on 1/5/2017) and 12 (Property B, evaluated on 2/20/2017), and the result is 10+12=22.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select date, sum(val),
       avg(sum(val) * 1.0) over (order by date) as average
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

You can use window functions in conjunction with aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't return what I expect.  For Total, it is the sum of value of Property A at the date and the value of Property B at the date.   For example, for the date of 2/20/2017, the value of Property A is 10 (since it was evaluated as 10 previously on 1/5/2017), and the value of Property B is 12 (since it was evaluated as 12 on 2/20/2017), so the total is (10+12=) 22, and the average is 11.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT [Date],
        Value+ISNULL(LAG(Value) OVER(order by (Select null) ),0) Total , 
        (Value+ISNULL(LAG(Value) OVER(order by (Select null) ),0))*1.0/2 As Average 
from Property_Evaluation
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it doesn't completely solve the problem (e.g. on 2/20 when the Properties were not evaluated alternatively), its usage of the LAG function gave me the hint to build the complete SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

With the hints from the answers posted here by the others, I built the complete SQL statement as below.

```
SELECT sq1.Date
   , sum(sq1.Value) Total
   , avg(sq1.Value) Average
from (
   select sq2.Date
      , sq2.Property
      , ISNULL(sq6.Value, (
         select sq3.Value 
         From (
            select sq6.Date
               , sq6.Property
               , isnull(sq6.Value, LAG(sq6.Value) OVER (partition by sq6.Property order by sq6.Date)) Value
            from (
               select isnull(sq4.Date, sq5.Date) Date
                  , isnull(sq4.Property, sq5.Property) Property
                  , sq4.Value Value
               from (
                  select distinct sq2.Date Date
                     , sq2.Property Property
                  from [PropertyEvaluation]
                  ) sq5
                  full outer join (
                     SELECT [Date] Date
                        , [Property] Property
                        , [Value] Value
                     FROM [PropertyEvaluation] 
                     where [Property] = sq2.Property) sq4
                  on sq5.Date = sq4.Date 
               ) sq6
            ) sq3
         where sq3.Date = sq2.Date
            and sq3.Property = sq2.Property
         )
     ) Value
   from (
      select sq7.Date Date
         , sq8.Property Property
      from (
         select distinct [Date] Date
         from [PropertyEvaluation]) sq7
         , (select distinct [Property] Property
         from [PropertyEvaluation]) sq8
      ) sq2
      left join (
         SELECT [Date] Date
            , [Property] Property
            , [Value] Value
         FROM [PropertyEvaluation] 
         ) sq6
      on sq2.Date = sq6.Date and sq2.Property = sq6.Property
   ) sq1
group by sq1.Date
order by 1
```

It returns the desired results:

```
Date        Total   Average
1/5/2017    10      10
2/3/2017    18      9
2/20/2017   22      11
3/1/2017    21      10.5
4/10/2017   24      12
```